# Can a method Invoked in Main thread from BG thread, be executed in the middle of event invocation list?

Tags: c#

I wounder when methods scheduled for invocation in other thread, get executed in targeted thread?

Could there be a situation when for example my Main thread is calling functions from event invocation list, and somewhere between event invocation list methods my method (which is not a part of a list) from other thread is executed?

Update: So, if I want to make sure some object is not modified during event invocation, I need to use some Busy property, even when all modification is done in single thread, because a method from other thread can be injected in my thread and modify this object during event invocation?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean having a queue of actions to execute on the Dispatcher, and then trying to execute something else from another thread via `BeginInvoke`. In that case the action gets added to the Dispatcher queue, according to MSDN, which hints that it is in fact executed after previously pending actions are finished.

Having said this, note that `BeginInvoke` has an overload for specifying a priority, so it is possible that an action which was queued later, but with a higher priority gets executed earlier than an action with a lower priority that was queued before it.